# OCR for handwritten mathematics

Tags: mathematical-software

I am in the process of scanning a large collection of handwritten notes.  They consist of diagrams and formulae with a relatively small proportion of actual words.  Of course it would be hopeless to get an OCR program to digest the diagrams or formulae, but it would be useful if I could get one to find and transcribe enough of the words to build an index.  Has anyone tried this kind of thing?

Comment: Tangentially related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3731/ocr-support-to-deduce-math-expressions-from-scanned-photos/3735#3735 (It is not entirely hopeless to get OCR to digest formulae.)

Comment: Use wetware.  It needn't even be grad students: ordinary MSc students work fine for this.  They will transcribe most of the formulas too, though usually not the diagrams.  


Comment: I thought MSc students are also grad students, by definition. Anyway, if you do opt for "wetware", be sparing... :)

Comment: If it is just about the *words* I do not see how this is specific to mathematics. Vote to close. 

Comment: The question is specific to mathematics because OCR systems use heuristics that may well break if the words are interspersed between non-words.  If many people had used many different systems then they would probably have information about which systems were more or less affected by this issue.  But perhaps the relevant experiments have not been done yet.

Comment: This is much more suited to stack overflow, voting to close.

Comment: @Igor: from where do you hold this opinion?  I work with people who do math handwriting recognition -- there is some deep CS, but the amount of required mathematical knowledge is huge to get anywhere.  I don't think anyone on stackoverflow would have a clue about what to do here (unless they happen to know about inftyreader!)

Comment: @Felix Goldberg: sorry, I think I meant to say ordinary BSc students.  

Comment: @IgorRivin There is [another discussion about this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570220/ocr-lib-for-math-formulas) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Related question on meta (about OCR of papers): http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2990/is-this-question-on-ocr-technology-appropriate

Comment: [tex.se]: [What is the status of generating LaTeX from handwriting (i.e., OCR)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1443) Also [math.meta.se]: [What tools can be used to extract MathJax/LaTeX from scanned input?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31182)

Answer (score 12):

I recommend www.inftyreader.org. They have a trial version, with long enough trial period to
 do a big project.
I've used InftyReader
 on a flakey old laptop and it did a pretty good job for a math book reissue.
 It took about half an
 hour or so to do each 40 page bundle of the disassembled book. It made systematic
 errors in the tex, many of which I was able to correct
 with some awk commands, but of course I still had
 to go through the whole thing tediously. I was not
 going for perfection, but just for something editable,
 and I think it came out better than required for this
 purpose.

Comment: The notes are *handwritten* I assume the book was not.

Comment: While I am very happy to have learned about the existence of InftyReader, I can confirm that it was not able to digest my handwritten notes.

Answer (score 9):

To supplement Bob Terrell's post, here is [an example from InftyReader](http://www.inftyreader.org/?p=61).

Snippet from an input image, scanned at 600dpi:

---

[image: Input]

---

Snippet from output of the corresponding LaTeX produced by [InftyReader](http://www.inftyreader.org/):

---

[image: LaTeX Output]

---

It's not perfect—$\partial z \partial \bar{z}$ becomes $\partial z k$—but it's pretty impressive!

Comment: Did you try it with something handwritten, too? This iw what the question seems to be about.

Comment: @quid: No. I am less interested in the question Neil posed than I am in learning what this neat software can do. InftyReader is designed to work on scanned images of printed mathematics, not handwriting.